# PHP implode function fails to work

Tags: php

i'm trying to use the implode function in php to inserting multiple checked values into a table but i get this error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1
```

PHP

```
if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "edusa_form")) {

$engine1 = implode(',', $_POST['written_tests']);
$insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO edusa_regis (fname) VALUES ('$engine1'))");
```

HTML

```
<input name="written_tests[]" type="checkbox" id="written_tests[]" value="SAT" />
        SAT&nbsp;
        <input name="written_tests[]" type="checkbox" id="written_tests[]" value="ACT" />
```

Comment: You have an extra `)` after `$_POST["MM_insert"]` in your if statement and also in your `sprintf` at the end at `'engine1'))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with the `implode` function. You have a bad syntax in your query.

```
$insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO edusa_regis (fname) VALUES ('$engine1'))");
```

You have an additional closing parenthesis in the query.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra `)` after $_POST["MM_insert"] in your if statement and also in your sprintf at the end at `'engine1'))`

```
if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"]) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "edusa_form")) {
$engine1 = implode(',', $_POST['written_tests']);
$insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO edusa_regis (fname) VALUES ('$engine1')");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "edusa_form")) {
    $engine1 = implode(',', $_POST['written_tests']);
    $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO edusa_regis (fname) VALUES ('$engine1')");
    mysqli_query($con, $insertSQL);
}
```